# Show "Black" when you "Scroll" down image

Tags: ios, scrollview, ipad

I have a pretty simple scroll view (code below) which i have a picture on

```
  self.detailViewController.scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 1200);
self.detailViewController.scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
```

However when i "Scroll to the extreme button or extreme top of the picture or extreme button of the "scroll view, it loops and shows the top of the picture or loops back to the buttom of the picture.

I was wondering if there was some sort of "no repeat" i could set so it shows "black" instead of back to the top of the picture.

Thank you.

Comment: What & how have you set the content of the scroll view (the subviews)?

Comment: self.detailViewController.scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seatwo.jpg"]];

Answer (score 0):

`colorWithPatternImage` tiles the image that it is given. So setting it as the background colour will always result in 'wrap around' if the scroll view can be scrolled outside the edges of the tile image.

To prevent this, choose one of:

1. Set the content size to the size of the tile image and turn off bouncing
2. Don't use `colorWithPatternImage`, use a `UIImageView` added as a subview of the scroll view.

Comment: UIImage  *scrollimga=[UIImage imageNamed:@"seatwo.jpg"];
   // UIImageView *scrolling=[UIImageView in]
    UIImageView *scrollimg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:scrollimga];
    [self.detailViewController.scroll addSubview:scrollimg];

Comment: Actually i have one more problem. removing the image fromm this view from the background. i tried 
[self.detailViewController.scroll removeFromSuperview]; but that removes the complete scrollview. Any tips on removing "seatwo" image?

Comment: You need to call `removeFromSuperview` on the view to be removed. So, the image view, not the scroll view.